# buffering issue in python GUI when running a python file using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

The Python GUI console is implemented by WxPython widgets.

When I run one python file using subprocess the output will send to the buffer. The GUI tool take a bit of time to show the buffer to screen. Therefore the time to show the output will be longer when running with command line.

And the python file print too much so the buffer is overflowing then GUI went to **Not responding** state.

I wish to show the output as live stream in GUI console.I have no idea about how to limit data to GUI buffer and preventing it from being not responding.

```
def runOtherScript(self,e):
        cmd = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "tool", "sample.py")
        cmdlist = ["python", cmd]

        proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlist, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)

        for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):
            self.output.write(line)
```

I have tried all options of `bufsize`.But still same behavior.Is there any possible solution for this?

Comment: Where your terminal app and `"sample.py"`. You call more argument without any declaration. You got terminal path if call app without path. So you got 3 (three) path : 1-Subproccess starting point, 2- Python Starting point, 3-Your script starting point. Need diagnose which app work with which directory path.

Comment: Clearly tell you: `commonFolder` has 'tool' folder and terminal app(called GUI.py).`tool` folder has `sample.py`. Updated the question with path.